# Windows - Metatrader 4 (32bit) - Freezing issues! Hypertreading? SingleCore overloading?

Tags: cpu, performance, freeze, hyper-threading

Ive been breaking my head on this issue for a while and i realy need some guidance. I think i might have solved it but i want to understand what the issue is if i need to upgrade or expand my system.

I am running this program Metatrader4 (32bit program - Trading program) I run an automated system which is higly cpu intensive but single core because metatrader4 is 32bit

When i installed 14x Metatrader4 and loaded my charts, my programs would freeze but still be running in the background. When markets slowed down i would be able to switch between programes again.

I now tried less Metatraders and its more stable (so far).  I have an I9-9900K and disabled Hypertreading in bios, used core affinity to have 1 core per program. (8 metatraders)

I think its running stable now, i havent had a "freeze".

Im trying to understand why 14x metatrader4 with less "data/trading pairs" would freeze compaired to a 8 program setup with more "data/trading pairs" loaded on 8x metatrader4.

My cpu would never go over 25% with a 14x metatrader4 installation & freeze the programs (Core0 & core15 in taskmanager 100%) but now that i use the 8x Metatrader4 with hypertreading disabled and used affinity to set 1 core per program my CPU is actually working.

Could it be that with 14x Metatrader4 (32bit) oné of the main core's gets overloaded and not distributed (bottleneck) so everything would just freeze up.

I might have to upgrade the next few months to be able to use 14x Metatrader4 programes. So i should look for a dedicated server with a lot of cores so i can use this affinity? So i can have 1 core assigned to 1 program or what would you suggest i do?

Any input would greatly be appreciated because ive been stuck on this problem for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

Even small programs are capable of generating large workloads, but since this is an closed-source app, the best avenues of searching for a solution are closed to us. Suggest you launch [Windows Resource Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor) with <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>resmon.exe<kbd>Enter</kbd> and watch each of your cores, as [explained here](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/12/28/a-detailed-windows-resource-monitor-guide/) and [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2011/01/04/how-to-pull-the-information-that-resource-monitor-resmon-exe-provides/).

Comment: yes i understand that, but i want to understand why its happening not if its happening. I am trying to understand why a small 32bit program can overload an I9-9900K to the point where all the programs are freezing. I want to understand this so in the future i can build a setup thats is more suited for a 32 bit program.

Comment: Clumsy and inefficient coding will do it every time. There isn't as much pressure to code elegantly as in olden days, as folks can just throw faster hardware at a slow app. Wish I could tell you what's going on, but I don't have that app's source code, or that app at all.